# How to implement JavaScript closures in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

I am using a function to count the number of clicks on the button as shown below:

```
$scope.counterFunc = (function(){
    var count = 0;
    console.log('i will be consoled only once');
    return function(){
        console.log(count);
        return ++count;
    }
})();
```

View:

```
<button ng-click="counterFunc()">click me</button>
<div>  
    {{ count value }}
</div>
```

I am able to console the `count value`, but how can i display it in the view.

I can use `$scope` variable to bind `count value` to view but my concern is that the `count` should not be altered by any other function outside the `counterFunc()`

Is there any other way to do this?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `counterFunc()` is already returning the incremented value each time it is executed by `ng-click`. You can assign it to a variable on your view like this

```
<button ng-click="count = counterFunc()">click me</button>
<div>
  {{ count }}
</div>
```

Note that `count` property will be created by above solution in your `$scope` but that will be different from `count` variable inside your `counterFunc()` and changing `$scope.count` will not affect `var count`. You can test this by adding another `button` for resetting the value of `$scope.count`

```
<button ng-click="count = counterFunc()">click me</button>
<div>
  {{ count }}
</div>
<button ng-click="count = 0">Reset</button>
```

Now, you will see that each time you press Reset `button`, displayed value will become `0`. But, when you press `click me` again, it will start from last value of `var count`.